# How do I convert a Word document to XML using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I want to convert Word documents (.doc and .docx) to XML. How i can do this using PHP?

Once I have done that, I have to add some data in that XML file.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

A Word document (docx) **is a xml file**. Simply unzip it.

Comment: Thnks, but how to save it as xml so i can add some data in that. And also file may be .doc or .docx. then for .doc what to do?

Comment: very true @Boldewyn. good if you just want the data. word/document.xml contains the data, but no formatting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431544/how-to-prepare-a-word-2007-document-so-that-c-can-pull-data-out-of-it-semantical/3431609#3431609

Comment: I want file as it is in format only i want to add some data in the bottom of the file. so i will use it later.

Comment: though i have never done it, you could add data to the word/document.xml and then zip it. or try phplivedocx.org

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive; // creating object of ZipArchive class.
$sUploadedFile = 'publisher.docx';
$zip->open("word_document/$sUploadedFile");
$aFileName = explode('.',$sUploadedFile);
$sDirectoryName =  current($aFileName);

if (!is_dir("word_document/$sDirectoryName")){
    mkdir("word_document/$sDirectoryName");
    $zip->extractTo("word_document/$sDirectoryName"); 
    copy("word_document/$sDirectoryName/word/document.xml", "xml_document/$sDirectoryName.xml");

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml_document/$sDirectoryName.xml");
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('w',"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
    $text = $xml->xpath('//w:t');

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($text); echo '</pre>';

    rrmdir("word_document/$sDirectoryName");
}

function rrmdir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
 }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to make an xml file via PHP is the XML DOM class.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp

Comment: Thanks for reply, there in my website student will upload the word document and using php i want to add some date in that document. So for that i have to convert it to xml and then add data in xml.

Comment: he is not asking about how to create an xml but to convert from docx to xml