# convert .DOCX file to XML file in php

Tags: php, xml

i am trying to convert `.docx` file in to XML. I just uploaded one `.docx` file but it showing errors for me.

here is my code

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
     $zip = new ZipArchive; // creating object of ZipArchive class.
 $sUploadedFile='word.docx';
      $zip->open("uploaded/$sUploadedFile");         
    $aFileName = explode('.',$sUploadedFile);           
    $sDirectoryName =  current($aFileName);
    if (!is_dir("uploaded/$sDirectoryName"))
      { 
        mkdir("uploaded/$sDirectoryName");
        $zip->extractTo("uploaded/$sDirectoryName"); 
      } 
         $xml = simplexml_load_file("uploaded/$sDirectoryName/word/document.xml");
         $xml->registerXPathNamespace('w',"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
        $text = $xml->xpath('//w:t');
     ?>
```

i am getting these errors

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity "uploaded/word/word/document.xml" in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\test\xml.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function registerXPathNamespace() on a
>   non- object in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\xml.php on line 14

can anyone help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi @Amit Gupta can you please help me out why this error is coming

Comment: I don't know much dear friend about conversion of doc to XML but I search and found useful link. Please check :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491363/how-do-i-convert-a-word-document-to-xml-using-php

Comment: when i use that code its not giving any errors,its just creating word_document folder inside publishrer folder thats it..its not creating xml file

Comment: @AmitGupta hi  i am getting one issue when i use tree structure can you please help me if you have an idea about that